# Casting ReadOnlyCollection<derivedType> to ReadOnlyCollection<baseType>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction...

How do I cast from `ReadOnlyCollection<myDerivedType>` to `ReadOnlyCollection<myBaseType>` without iterating or "newing up" a copy?

I am using .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can implicitly convert a `ROC<Derived>` into an `IEnumerable<Base>` in C# 4, but not into a `ROC<Base>`.

That is unfortunate; it would be really nice to be able to do covariant conversions on immutable types.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can, as the generic parameter T isn't defined as an `out` (as has been pointed out .net doesn't support Covariance and Contravariance in classes).

[ReadOnlyCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx)

You would have to use LINQ, such as `readOnlyColl.Cast<myBaseType>();`, or a loop. Internally LINQ would use a loop / iteration, making a new copy.

Comment: Or more generally .Net doesn't support covariance/contravariance in classes

Comment: I thought that in .NET 4, this was supported?

Comment: @thebowler yse for delegates and interfaces

Answer (score 0):

with Linq

```
yourCollection.Cast<myBaseType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't you will have to project `ReadOnlyCollection<myDerivedType>` into `ReadOnlyCollection<myBaseType>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that covariance and contravariance is allowed in C# for generic types. **Generics don’t support this—they’re invariant**.

I think that only generic delegates in C#4 has limited support for covariance and contravariance.

Comment: In C# 4 there is covariance and contravariance on generic *interfaces* and *delegates* when the type arguments are *reference types* and the legal variances are stated at the declarations of the type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, so you're probably better off passing around interfaces like `IEnumerable<T>` or `ICollection<T>` instead of concrete classes like `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Then you can do, as others have suggested:

```
collection.Cast<myBaseType>();
```

Comment: You gave me a different approach, here. I changed to using IEnumerable and found life a better place...